# Как менять, а не прибавлять числа месяца при клике в select'е на другой месяц?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сейчас даты не заменяются, а дописываются к текущему месяцу. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе любого месяца в select'е даты менялись?

```js
const createCalendar = (id, year, month) => {
    let elem = document.getElementById(id);
    let mon = month - 1;
    let d = new Date(year, mon);
    let table = '<div class="table"><div>пн</div><div>вт</div><div>ср</div><div>чт</div><div>пт</div><div>сб</div><div>вс</div>';
    
    // Получаем номер дня недели, от 0(пн) до 6(вс)
    const getDay = () => { 
    let day = d.getDay();
    if (day === 0) day = 7;
    return day;
    };
    getDay();

    // Заполнить первый ряд пустыми ячейками от пн
    const fillFirstRow = () => {
        for (var i = 1; i < getDay(d); i++) {
            table += '<div></div>';
        }
    };
    fillFirstRow();

    //Ячейки календаря с датами
    const fillTable = () => {
        for (let i = 1; i <= d.getDate(); i++) {
            if (d.getMonth() <= mon) {
                table += '<div class="day" data-id="">' + d.getDate() + '</div>';
                elem.innerHTML = table;
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
            }
        };
    };
    fillTable();


    
    // Выводим текущий месяц через select
    const getMonth = () => {
        let selectM = document.querySelector('.month');
        for (let i = 0; i < selectM.length; i++) {
            if (selectM[i].value == mon) {
                selectM.value = mon + 1;
            }
        }

        const getIndexDays = (month, year) => {
            return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        };
 
        selectM.addEventListener('change', () => {

            let currentMonth = selectM.selectedIndex + 1;
            for (let i = 1; i < getIndexDays(currentMonth, year) + 1; i++) {
                table += '<div class="day" data-id="">' + i + '</div>';
                elem.innerHTML = table;
                console.log(i);
            }
        })
    };
    getMonth();

}

createCalendar('calendar', 2019, 8);
```

```css
.table {
    max-width: 300px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(69, 80, 95, 0.445);
  }
  
.day {
  min-width: 32px;
  min-height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
  
  .day:hover {
    background-color: #F2F5F9;
  }
  
  #calendar {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 30px rgba(19, 24, 31, 0.08);
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Graphik LCG;
  }
  
  .month {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Graphik LCG;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #F2F5F9;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: ease-out 0.1s;
  }
  
  .month:hover {
    background-color: rgb(213, 219, 226);
    transition: ease-out 0.1s;
  }
  
  select {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <select class="month" onchange="">
        <option value="1">Январь</option>
        <option value="2">Февраль</option>
        <option value="3">Март</option>
        <option value="4">Апрель</option>
        <option value="5">Май</option>
        <option value="6">Июнь</option>
        <option value="7">Июль</option>
        <option value="8">Август</option>
        <option value="9">Сентябрь</option>
        <option value="10">Октябрь</option>
        <option value="11">Ноябрь</option>
        <option value="12">Декабрь</option>
      </select> 

      <select class="month">
        <option value="1">2019</option>
      </select>

      <div id="calendar"></div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала создадим `defaultTable`, где сохраним значение таблицы по умолчанию.

```
const defaultTable = '<div class="table"><div>пн</div><div>вт</div><div>ср</div><div>чт</div><div>пт</div><div>сб</div><div>вс</div>';
let table = defaultTable;
```

Затем необходимо обнулять таблицу при клике на новый месяц. (`table = defaultTable;`)

```
const getMonth = () => {
        let selectM = document.querySelector('.month');
        for (let i = 0; i < selectM.length; i++) {
            if (selectM[i].value == mon) {
                selectM.value = mon + 1;
            }
        }

        const getIndexDays = (month, year) => {
            return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        };

        selectM.addEventListener('change', () => {

            let currentMonth = selectM.selectedIndex + 1;
            table = defaultTable;
            for (let i = 1; i < getIndexDays(currentMonth, year) + 1; i++) {
                table += '<div class="day" data-id="">' + i + '</div>';
                elem.innerHTML = table;
            }
        })
    };
```